# Three.js Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext':

Tags: three.js

This issue originated with the previous issue of html5 video not playing on android phones. ([Three.js WebGLRenderered videos don't play on android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109487/three-js-webglrenderered-videos-dont-play-on-android-phones))

And as mrdoob mentioned, video.play() should be explicit on mobile devices through user initiated events such as click. Having done this, I have been able to play the file. However I am only able to hear the audio part of the video. The screen is still blank. Moreover, I see the following exception on the dev console.

**Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The video element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded. three.min.js:507**

I am not loading any image through my code as you can see in the code below and the error seems to be thrown in three.min.js file. (The code below is a slightly modified version of http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_video to make it run on mobile device)

Please note that this happens only on mobile device. The example works flawlessly on the web.

Your help is much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - materials - video</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
                font-family:Monospace;
                font-size:13px;
                text-align:center;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align:center;
            }

            a {
                color:#0078ff;
            }

            #info {
                color:#fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px; width: 100%;
                padding: 5px;
                z-index:100;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="info">
            <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - webgl video demo. playing <a href="http://durian.blender.org/" target="_blank">sintel</a> trailer
        </div>

        <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/shaders/ConvolutionShader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/MaskPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/BloomPass.js"></script>
        <script src="js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>

        <video id="video" autoplay loop style="display:none">
            <source src="textures/sintel.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
            <source src="textures/sintel.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
        </video>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var container;

            var camera, scene, renderer, element;

            var video, texture, material, mesh;

            var composer;

            var mouseX = 0;
            var mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            var cube_count,

                meshes = [],
                materials = [],

                xgrid = 20,
                ygrid = 10;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 500;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.set( 0.5, 1, 1 ).normalize();
                scene.add( light );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                element=renderer.domElement;
                element.addEventListener('click', fullscreen, false);

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                video = document.getElementById( 'video' );

                texture = new THREE.Texture( video );
                texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
                texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
                texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
                texture.generateMipmaps = false;

                //

                var i, j, ux, uy, ox, oy,
                    geometry,
                    xsize, ysize;

                ux = 1 / xgrid;
                uy = 1 / ygrid;

                xsize = 480 / xgrid;
                ysize = 204 / ygrid;

                var parameters = { color: 0xffffff, map: texture },
                    material_base = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( parameters );

                renderer.initMaterial( material_base, scene.__lights, scene.fog );

                cube_count = 0;

                for ( i = 0; i < xgrid; i ++ )
                for ( j = 0; j < ygrid; j ++ ) {

                    ox = i;
                    oy = j;

                    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( xsize, ysize, xsize );

                    change_uvs( geometry, ux, uy, ox, oy );

                    materials[ cube_count ] = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( parameters );

                    material = materials[ cube_count ];

                    material.hue = i/xgrid;
                    material.saturation = 1 - j/ygrid;

                    material.color.setHSL( material.hue, material.saturation, 0.5 );

                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                    mesh.position.x =   ( i - xgrid/2 ) * xsize;
                    mesh.position.y =   ( j - ygrid/2 ) * ysize;
                    mesh.position.z = 0;

                    mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 1;

                    scene.add( mesh );

                    mesh.dx = 0.001 * ( 0.5 - Math.random() );
                    mesh.dy = 0.001 * ( 0.5 - Math.random() );

                    meshes[ cube_count ] = mesh;

                    cube_count += 1;

                }

                renderer.autoClear = false;

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

                // postprocessing

                var renderModel = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );
                var effectBloom = new THREE.BloomPass( 1.3 );
                var effectCopy = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );

                effectCopy.renderToScreen = true;

                composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );

                composer.addPass( renderModel );
                composer.addPass( effectBloom );
                composer.addPass( effectCopy );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }
            function fullscreen() {

                video.play();
                console.log(video);
                  if (container.requestFullscreen) {
                    container.requestFullscreen();
                  } else if (container.msRequestFullscreen) {
                    container.msRequestFullscreen();
                  } else if (container.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                    container.mozRequestFullScreen();
                  } else if (container.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                    container.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                  }
                }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                composer.reset();

            }

            function change_uvs( geometry, unitx, unity, offsetx, offsety ) {

                var faceVertexUvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ];

                for ( var i = 0; i < faceVertexUvs.length; i ++ ) {

                    var uvs = faceVertexUvs[ i ];

                    for ( var j = 0; j < uvs.length; j ++ ) {

                        var uv = uvs[ j ];

                        uv.x = ( uv.x + offsetx ) * unitx;
                        uv.y = ( uv.y + offsety ) * unity;

                    }

                }

            }


            function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * 0.3;

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();

            }

            var h, counter = 1;

            function render() {

                var time = Date.now() * 0.00005;

                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                if ( video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA ) {

                    if ( texture ) texture.needsUpdate = true;

                }

                for ( i = 0; i < cube_count; i ++ ) {

                    material = materials[ i ];

                    h = ( 360 * ( material.hue + time ) % 360 ) / 360;
                    material.color.setHSL( h, material.saturation, 0.5 );

                }

                if ( counter % 1000 > 200 ) {

                    for ( i = 0; i < cube_count; i ++ ) {

                        mesh = meshes[ i ];

                        mesh.rotation.x += 10 * mesh.dx;
                        mesh.rotation.y += 10 * mesh.dy;

                        mesh.position.x += 200 * mesh.dx;
                        mesh.position.y += 200 * mesh.dy;
                        mesh.position.z += 400 * mesh.dx;

                    }

                }

                if ( counter % 1000 === 0 ) {

                    for ( i = 0; i < cube_count; i ++ ) {

                        mesh = meshes[ i ];

                        mesh.dx *= -1;
                        mesh.dy *= -1;

                    }

                }

                counter ++;

                renderer.clear();
                composer.render();

            }


        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173727 the "video" attribute should have this set:

```
video.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
```

But this alone won't do the trick. This has to be set before .load() and .play(). I had this after .load() and it did not work. So do it like this:

```
video.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
video.src = "video/test.m4v";
video.src = "video/test.mp4";
video.load(); // must call after setting/changing source
video.play();
```

This is solution is for videos that don't play on mobile devices specifically due to the security error seen as above.

---

Just to be clear `crossorigin` settings tell the browser to ask the server for permission to use the video. The server still has to give that permission. If the server doesn't give permission setting the `crossorigin` attribute won't let you use the video.

Comment: i tried above solution, i dont get the error anymore but the video still does not play in chrome for android but does in firefox for android...

Comment: Mark, do you see any exceptions/errors being thrown? Also three.js website has examples for most things you can do with it. Find one like that and see if it works in chrome. This may tell you if its a chrome or code issue.

Comment: on my desktop it works fine. But on chrome for android, I see no exceptions but the following warning: WebGLRenderingContext]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete' (index):1
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no video

Comment: were you able to get this working on chrome for android?

Comment: Yes. If I recall correctly it had to be the latest version of chrome browser. Since older versions of chrome did not support webgl.

Comment: I think there are other question on stackoverflow that addresses this. Try this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954036/dartweb-gl-render-warning-texture-bound-to-texture-unit-0-is-not-renderable

Comment: ok thanks, ill try that, though not sure how to convert to three.js

Answer (score 4):

This is the top result in Google for this issue, so if you are experiencing this error outside the context of a mobile issue (which is how I found this), try running the page on a local server in order to resolve the cross origin problem. So for instance if you have python you could try:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

From the directory where your page exists, and then the page will be available from http://localhost:8000. Or use a local server of your choice.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for this 'little hint' of trying to run it via a local server. :-)

Comment: * eyeroll * well excuse me. This cynicism is why I hate SO.

Comment: i think you're getting it wrong. no cynicism intended. I mean it. I lost a whole day debugging and trying to figure out why my 360 video wouldn't play. Your post actually solved it. Therefore thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misinterpreted. I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: I confirm it works on local server. Apache2 on MacOs with Laravel.

Comment: This helped me too.