# one three.js example of video on iPhone 6s did not work( only black panel)

Tags: javascript, ios, three.js, webgl

one three.js example of video on iPhone 6s  did not work( only black panel)

https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Video.html

But the example works fine on PC desktop browser.
It failed in Safari & Chronme on iPhone 6s

Answer (score 2):

As of 2019 the solution for iOS is

1. you have to start the video in user gesture event like 'click' or 'touchstart'

   Otherwise the browser will refuse to play the video

   ```
   someElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    videoElement.play();
   });
   ```
2. you have to set `playsInline` to true

   ```
   videoElement.playsInline = true;
   ```

Here's a working example as of iOS 12

http://webglsamples.org/video/video.html

Answer (score 0):

There is similar question here and the cause is same I guess.

[Three.js WebGLRenderered videos don't play on android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109487/three-js-webglrenderered-videos-dont-play-on-android-phones)

Answer (score 0):

I found another process playing video file was started by the HTML5 web. But I think this is not a good user experience with iPhone 5. Temporarily,  the problem was solved by programming the native code of video-playing and sending the app onto the Iphone 6s in ios 9.3.